# p4v doesn't delete new files added through `p4 add` after shelving

Tags: perforce, p4v

I've tried to shelve files today and checked the `Revert checked out files after they are shelved` option, and after shelving the files some files have been reverted, but some remained. It appeared that these were new files added through `p4 add`. Is it default behavior to not remove such files after shelving? Is there a way to remove them as part of shelving process?

Comment: At the command-line level, this is the difference between `p4 revert` and `p4 revert -w`.

Comment: so what you are saying is that p4 shelve doesnt revert files, this is accomplished by a separate command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did in P4V (shelve with reverting) is really a plain combination of two commands: `shelve` and `revert`. Behind the scenes, P4V will shelve your work (as it surely did) and then revert everything in your changelist.

Now, the `revert` command reverts `p4 add`s in such a way that they disappear from your changelist (the essence of reverting) but they remain on the local filesystem (to prevent inadvertent loss of code/data). Yes, you can argue that in this respect `revert` does not do a very good job of reverting your work completely, but obviously Perforce have decided to play it safe by not deleting your work.

As @Bryan Pendleton says, you can use `p4 revert -w` instead of plain `p4 revert` when you want to also delete your `p4 add`s from the filesystem. It's not a separate command, just a variant of `p4 revert`. However, there's no way to specify the `-w` flag (the `-w` behaviour) when running the "Shelve-and-Revert" combo action from P4V. (In fact, there's no way to specify `-w` even in the plain "Revert" action from P4V.)

I'm assuming you won't switch from P4V to the command-line (to run `p4 shelve` followed by `p4 revert -w`) just for this reason, so just remember that P4V has this little quirk and if needed, delete your local files after reverting them.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought. One clarification though, you're said _but obviously Perforce have decided to play it safe by not deleting your work_ - but I don't see a way to my work being lost since all of it is shelved, even the newly added files, correct?

Comment: That's true in the "Shelve-and-Revert" combo, but not in a general "Revert" action.